# How to do MySQL query to fetch other table field value, in case of existance?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Suppose we have this model:

[image]

As you see industry_id can be null. Can I fetch industry.name (if any), user.description, profile.name and project.title (all project titles) he/she has with a single MySQL query while having user.id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `JOIN` the two tables:

```
SELECT
  i.name,
  u.id
FROM Industry AS i
LEFT JOIN `User` AS u ON u.industry_id = i.industry_id;
```

---

### Update:

For multiple tables:

```
SELECT 
  i.Name  AS InustryName,
  p.Name  AS UserName,
  u.Description,
  j.title AS ProjectTitle
FROM Industry AS i
INNER JOIN User    AS u ON i.id      = u.id
INNER JOIN Profile AS p ON p.user_id = u.id
INNER JOIN Project AS j ON u.id      = j.user_id;
```

**Note that:** I used `INNER JOIN` between the tables, this will give you only the matched rows from the joined tables, you might need to use LEFT JOIN instead of innner join to  include the untmatched rows, i.e., to get those industries that has no entries in the other tables. See this blog post:

- [**A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins**](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Thank you Gamal, But what exactly your Yes, means!

Comment: @HPM - I meant, Yes you can fetch `industry.name` with a single MySQL query while having user.id returned in the same query. Is this what you were trying to do?

Comment: yes, but what if there are 4 other related table (they have user_id as foreign key). Can I use this solution? how? (I think that way main table should be user in query, isn't it?)

Comment: @HPM you can `JOIN` multiple tables, can you please edit your question and show those four tables structures, how they are related and what do you want to select from them. it will be very helpful.